# binary to base10 in java with main method and TWO classes/method (boolean and

Tags: java, methods, binary, boolean, converters

I am a beginner programmer. This is what I have so far. The directions for the question are kind of difficult. Here is what I am trying to accomplish..

You will write a program that converts binary numbers to base 10 numbers. This program will ask the user to enter a binary number. You will have to verify that what is entered by the user only has 0s and 1s. In the case the user entered letters, you have to keep asking the user for another input. When the input is valid, you will convert the binary number to a base 10 number. Please use the Question1.java file provided in the A2.zip file.

Valid input - In order to check if the input is valid your program should call the CheckInputCorrect method, which takes a String as an input parameter and returns a boolean value. An input string is considered valid if it corresponds to a number in binary representation.
More specifically, in the CheckInputCorrect method, you should scan this string to make sure it only contains ‘0’ or ‘1’ characters. As soon as you find a character that is not ‘0’ or ‘1’, the method should returns false. If the method reaches the end of the input string (i.e. all characters are ‘0’ or ‘1’) the method should return true.

Converter - At this point we assume that the input string is valid (checked with the CheckInputCorrect method). To convert the input from binary to base 10, you must implement the BinaryToNumber method. The BinaryToNumber method should take as parameter a String and return an integer, which corresponds to converted value in base 10.
The binary conversion should work as follows. For each digit in the binary number, if the digit is ‘1’ you should add the corresponding decimal value ( 20 for the rightmost digit, 21 for the next digits to the left, 22 for the next one, and so on) to a variable that will hold the final result to be returned. This can be easily accomplished by using a loop.

1) Am I on the right path?
2) I don't exactly know what I am doing and need you to help me figure that out....

Update1:

When I run this vvvv: It says "Please enter a binary number for me to convert: and then a place for me to type in my answer but whatever i put it just returns another box for me to type in but stops and doesn't evaluated anything.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Question1
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    System.out.println("Please enter a binary number for me to convert to decimal: ");   
    Scanner inputKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputUser = inputKeyboard.nextLine();          
    boolean BinaryNumber = false;
    String inputString = "";

    while (!BinaryNumber){
      inputString = inputKeyboard.next();
      BinaryNumber = CheckInputCorrect(inputString);
      System.out.println("You have given me a " + BinaryNumber + "string of binary numbers.");

    }
    int finalNumber = BinaryToNumber(inputString);
    System.out.println("Congratulations, your binary number is " + finalNumber + ".");


  }

  public static boolean CheckInputCorrect(String input)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++)
    {
      while (i < input.length());

      if (input.charAt(i) != '0' && input.charAt(i) != '1')
      {return false;}
      i++;
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static int BinaryToNumber(String numberInput)
  {
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberInput.length(); i++){
      if (numberInput.charAt(i)=='1')
      {
        total += (int)Math.pow(2,numberInput.length() - 1 - i);
      }
    }

    return total;

  } 
}




Original: 



    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class Question1
    {
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
    int binarynumber;
    int arraySize = {0,1};
    int[] binaryinput = new int[arraySize];


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a binary number");
    binarynumber = in.nextInt();

    if (binarynumber <0)
    {
      System.out.println("Error: Not a positive integer");

    }

    if (CheckInputCorrect) = true;
    {
      System.out.print(CheckInputCorrect);

    }

    public static boolean CheckInputCorrect(String input);
     {
       boolean b = true;
       int x, y;
       x = 0
       y = 1

       b = x || y


       while (b >= 0 {
         System.out.print("Please enter a binary number")
           for (int i = 0; i < binarynumber.length; i++)
         {
           binaryinput[i] = in.nextInt();
       if (binaryinput[i] = b.nextInt();
           System.out.printl("Binary number is:" + binaryinput);
           break outer;

         if (binarynumber != b)
       {
         System.out.println("Error: Not a binary number")
       }

      return true; 
     }

     }



     public static int BinaryToNumber(String numberInput)
     {
            int remainder;

            if (binarynumber <= 1) {
                System.out.print(number);
                return;   // KICK OUT OF THE RECURSION
            }

            remainder = number %2; 
            printBinaryform(number >> 1);
            System.out.print(remainder);
          return 0; 
         }

         }
          }
```

Comment: To find out, if you're on the right spot, you could fix all your code errors (for example in this line `if (binaryinput[i] = b.nextInt();`) and use a debugger to test every single step in your program.

Comment: There are a few things wrong that I have noticed. You can't get the length of an int by using binary number.length, use logarithms for that. You aren't actually accepting a binary number but are accepting an integer. Try using Scanner.next() instead and using String.charAt() to check if there is a one or zero at a certain spot. You are using .nextInt() with a boolean, which doesn't make any sense. You can't set an int to {0, 1}, what are you trying to do here?

Comment: To your edit: this line `while (i < input.length());` looks pretty infinite to me. It runs while `i` is smaller than `input.length()` and has no body. Therefore `i` can never change and become larger than `input.length()`.

Comment: And `inputString = inputKeyboard.next();` request another input after the first one. Why you're not using `inputUser` for evaluation instead?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in my comments, your updated code contains two errors

- `while (i < input.length());` is an infinite loop, because it has no body. Therefore `i` cannot be increased and will stay lower than `input.length()`.
- `inputString = inputKeyboard.next();` request another input after the first one and the first input will be ignored.

This is a fixed and commented version of your updated code:

```
public class Question1 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a binary number for me to convert to decimal: ");
    Scanner inputKeyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String inputUser = inputKeyboard.nextLine();
    //boolean BinaryNumber = false; // not needed anymore
    //String inputString = ""; // not needed too

    while (!checkInputCorrect(inputUser)) { // there is no reason for using a boolean var here .. directly use the returned value of this method
      System.out.println("You have given me an invalid input. Please enter a binary number: "); // changed this message a little bit
      inputUser = inputKeyboard.nextLine(); // re-use the "old" variable inputUser here
    }

    int finalNumber = binaryToNumber(inputUser);
    System.out.println("Congratulations, your decimal number is " + finalNumber + ".");
  }

  public static boolean checkInputCorrect(String input) { // method names should start with a lower case letter
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length(); i++) {
      //while (i < input.length()); // this loop is deadly. Please think about why
      if (input.charAt(i) != '0' && input.charAt(i) != '1') {
        return false;
      }
      //i++; // what is the purpose of this? The "for" loop will increment "i" for you
    }
    return true;
  }

  public static int binaryToNumber(String numberInput) { //method name ... lower case letter ;)
    int total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numberInput.length(); i++) {
      if (numberInput.charAt(i) == '1') {
        total += (int) Math.pow(2, numberInput.length() - 1 - i);
      }
    }

    return total;
  }
}
```